# Can Channel Divinity: Preserve Life target swallowed creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, targeting, cover

I saw [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170228/can-you-cast-mass-cure-wounds-on-someone-who-has-been-swallowed-by-a-creature) and was reminded of something that happened in one of my games recently:  I, as a Life Cleric, used my Channel Divinity: Preserve Life feature on an ally who had been swallowed (It didn't affect the outcome significantly; I had two other possible plans that would probably have saved said ally).

But I'm curious.  My ally had total cover, which prevented targetting her with a spell (say, Mass Cure Wounds, as in the linked question).  But Preserve Life is not a spell.  RAW, is this legal?

Comment: Somewhat similar questions about non-spells and total cover: "[Do Gaze Effects work through a Wall of Force?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132122)" and "[Can the generic teleport Action available to some monsters be used to move through transparent, total cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141823)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, this works. (RAW)

[Total cover](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TotalCover) specifies,

> can't be targeted directly by an **attack** or a **spell**. (PHB, pg. 196)

[Channel Divinity: Preserve Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LifeDomain) is neither an attack, nor a spell, so the only eligibility condition for targets is that a creature be

> within 30 feet of you. (PHB, pg. 60)

This is a obviously strict rules as written interpretation, and it relies on the principle that [there are no secret rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), e.g. there is no secret rule that total cover prevents class features or racial abilities that are not attacks or spells from targeting the covered creature.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's the RAW answer, which I asked for, even if I would (in the future) rule with the other answer.

Comment: I feel like thematically this makes sense as well, since you're literally asking your god to intercede on you behalf, and something like a mere 13' of digestive tract isn't really going to stop a god.

Answer (score 6):

### Channel Divinity: Preserve Life requires a clear path to its targets

The rules on "[A Clear Path to the Target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget)" state:

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover. [...]

Thus, if something is behind total cover (like when swallowed), it cannot be targeted.

---

#### The quoted rules do *not* apply only to spells

The rules quoted above are found in "[Chapter 10: Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Spellcasting)" in the section "[Casting a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell)", subsection "[Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets)" but that does not mean those rules apply exclusively to spells.

Also found in chapter 10, in the same Casting a Spell section, are the rules that *define* cones, cubes, cylinders, lines, and spheres. Clearly *those* rules apply to non-spells (those shapes are used for things that are not spells), and I see no reason the rules requiring a clear path would not *also* apply to non-spells.

Comment: Are there really no Crawford tweets on issues like this? Seems like something someone would have brought up with him before.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I didn't find anything since all his regarding total cover are about spells (He has said that being behind total cover means you are outside of a creature's blindsight radius, but that's quite different and barely supports this). Not to mention the fact that his tweets are not official rules or rulings and are merely indications of what he felt *at the time he made the tweet* (he's gone back on his own tweets numerous times)

Comment: Anyway, I upvoted, I think you've got RAI right on in this answer.

Comment: How do you feel about [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/171516/62294), does *dream* require a clear path to the target?

Comment: @Thomas To chat!

Comment: This answer would benefit from comparison to other channel divinity options, and if they assume spell casting rules or specify explicit rules themselves. For example Turn Undead by this interpretation would require clear path, and *"..or can hear you"* in rules is not actually sufficient, there must also be spell line of effect. This sounds like "secret rule" to me.